# Remove <div> tag from rails text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, gsub

I try to remove a div tag like this;

```
<div id="line_small_spacing" style="font-size: 15px; font-family: Arial, 'Open Sans'; height: 2px; width: 697px; color: #444444;">&nbsp;</div>
```

using the following code;

```
object.gsub(/<div.*?>|<\/div>/, '')
```

But it is not removed, anything wrong with the gsub expression?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use gsub! to apply all the modifications to the current object.

```
object.gsub!(/<div.*?>|<\/div>/, '')
```

gsub will only works if you assign it to a variable

```
a = object.gsub(/<div.*?>|<\/div>/, '')
```

Reference:
http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/String.html#method-i-gsub

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me, may be missing escape characters when creating object.

```
irb(main):003:0> object = '<div id="line_small_spacing" style="font-size: 15px; font-family: Arial, \'Open Sans\'; height: 2px; width: 697px; color: #444444;">&nbsp;</div>'
=> "<div id=\"line_small_spacing\" style=\"font-size: 15px; font-family: Arial, 'Open Sans'; height: 2px; width: 697px; color: #444444;\">&nbsp;</div>"
irb(main):007:0> a = object.gsub(/<div.*?>|<\/div>/, '')
=> "&nbsp;"
irb(main):008:0> a
=> "&nbsp;"
```